# How to create a 2D array where all elements have the same number?

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to create an array size 576x720 where each element has the same number.

I tried it like this but did not succeed:

```
#Define row and column
int row = 576, col = 720;
#Initialize 2D character array
char array2D[row][col] = {[0 ... (row-1)][0 ... (col-1)] = '137'};
```

How can I create such an array?

Comment: `array2D = [[0]*row for i in range(col)]` is the simple way

Comment: Do you need it in C or python language?

Comment: could this help? x = [['137' for i in range(col)] for x in range(row)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally speaking, the easiest way would be using `numpy` module and `full` function:

```py
row = 576
col = 720
valueToFill = 137
numpy.full((row, col), valueToFill)
```

##### Output

```
array([[137, 137, 137, ..., 137, 137, 137],
       [137, 137, 137, ..., 137, 137, 137],
       [137, 137, 137, ..., 137, 137, 137],
       ...,
       [137, 137, 137, ..., 137, 137, 137],
       [137, 137, 137, ..., 137, 137, 137],
       [137, 137, 137, ..., 137, 137, 137]])
```

If you wanna make sure the shape of the matrix is as same as what you asked for, you can try calling `shape` attribute on the array:

```py
row = 576
col = 720
valueToFill = 1
array = numpy.full((row, col), valueToFill)
array.shape
```

which results in:

```
(576, 720)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
row,col = 576, 720
array2D = [[137]*row for i in range(col)]
```